# Ansible で、すべてのノードで成功することを確認してから次のステップを実行したい

Tags: ansible

Ansible のタスクを記述していました。その中で、すべてのノードで成功することを確認してから次のステップを実行したいような、ステップがありました。この場合、どのノードであっても fail したならば、その全体のタスク自体を abort してほしいです。これは、 ansible の機能によって実現できますでしょうか。

何も考えずに普通にステップを記述していくと、失敗したノードはそこで実行が止まるが、そのほかのノードは継続して実行が進んでいくので、この質問をしています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[any_error_fatal](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#interrupt-execution-on-any-error)を指定すると、あるノードがタスクの実行に失敗した時に他のノードもそこで abort します。

Comment: ドキュメントを読む限り、私がほしかったものは、このオプションであるのではないかと思われるので、 accept します。